# IIS HTTPS without redirect

Tags: iis, https

Brain teaser for you all. I inherited a few servers with IIS that the old team somehow made https forced. I just created a new site in this IIS and can not figure out how they did it. Unfortunately, the old team left on bad terms and they are not an option. 
URL Rewrite is not installed and I did check the default aspx file and there is no coding in there for https. 
HTTP redirect is not enabled. 
SSL is set to ignore
I am at a loss on what they did to make this work.

Comment: `default.aspx` is clearly the wrong place to look for redirection. If you cannot find any IIS settings for such redirection, it is very likely to be in the code, and `global.asax` is the most likely place (though other places might be as well).

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that.